# UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier is not working relaunching after its expires

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uibackgroundtask

I have a app that fetch some content from server via REST api after every 5 mins in background using the `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier`. My problem is that this works fine for 1,2 hours and then after it is expired it never re starts the background task. The code I am using is given below,

In AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
          UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

            self.expirationHandler = ^{
                [app endBackgroundTask:self.bgTask];
                self.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        //      self.bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:expirationHandler];
                NSLog(@"Expired");
                self.jobExpired = YES;
                while(self.jobExpired) {
                    // spin while we wait for the task to actually end.
                    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
                }
                self.bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:expirationHandler];
                // Restart the background task so we can run forever.
                [self startBackgroundTask];
            };
            self.bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:expirationHandler];

            [self monitorBatteryStateInBackground];
    }

    - (void)monitorBatteryStateInBackground
    {
        NSLog(@"Monitoring update");
        self.background = YES;
        [self startBackgroundTask];
    }

    - (void)startBackgroundTask
    {
        NSLog(@"Restarting task");
        // Start the long-running task.
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            // When the job expires it still keeps running since we never exited it. Thus have the expiration handler
            // set a flag that the job expired and use that to exit the while loop and end the task.
            while(self.background && !self.jobExpired)
            {
                [self uploadPhotostoServer];
                [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:240.0];
            }

            self.jobExpired = NO;
        });
    }
```

In expired section it do come but never calls the method `[self startBackgroundTask]`

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You can't run forever in the background on IOS. Eventually you will consume the available cumulative background time (about 3 minutes). You can use background fetch but that won't run every 5 minutes. Better to design your app to use push notification when there is actually new data

Comment: @Paulw11, You said cumulative 3 minutes that means I'm allowed to call background fetch for 3 minutes only in total once app goes to background or this time for one time background fetch request?

Comment: I believe the 3 minutes resets once your app comes to the foreground - You can check the `backgroundTimeRemaining` property on `UIApplication` to see how much time remains at any point